# Execute dynamic sql "alter database" inside trigger

Tags: sql-server, database, dynamic, triggers, alter

I want to alter a database to add a filegroup using dynamic SQL inside a trigger,
but the following error occurs:

> ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

1. Commit transactions before executing the statement
2. Set implicit transactions off and on
3. Call stored procedure from the trigger to execute the statement

This because the trigger executes in its own transaction.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There are a number of restrictions on the ALTER DATABASE command, including that it cannot execute if there are any sessions in that database (for most of its options). This includes the session executing the ALTER DATABASE. So if your trigger is trying to alter the database that the trigger is in, you probably cannot do it directly.

Comment: when user inserts a record in a table, a filegroup should be added to another database how can i implement this??

Comment: Have you thought about posting the information you need to set up the filegroup to a queueing table, and have a separate process create the filegroup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider following quotes from documentation:

---

1. [ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174269.aspx#Anchor_2)

> The ALTER DATABASE statement must run in autocommit mode (the default transaction management mode) and is not allowed in an explicit or implicit transaction.

---

2. [Autocommit Transactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> A connection to an instance of the Database Engine operates in autocommit mode until a BEGIN TRANSACTION statement starts an explicit transaction, or implicit transaction is set on. When the explicit transaction is committed or rolled back, or when implicit transaction mode is turned off, the connection returns to autocommit mode.

---

3. [Rollbacks and Commits in Stored Procedures and Triggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187844%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#Anchor_1), on Triggers:

> A trigger operates as if there were an outstanding transaction in effect when the trigger is executed. This is true whether the statement firing the trigger is in an implicit or explicit transaction.
>
> When a statement begins executing in *autocommit mode*, there is an implied BEGIN TRANSACTION to allow the recovery of all modifications generated by the statement if it encounters an error. This implied transaction has no effect on the other statements in the batch because it is either committed or rolled back when the statement completes. This implied transaction is still in effect, however, when a trigger is called.

---

The conclusion is, you can't do what you want from inside a trigger.

Comment: thanks , but how can i execute this scenario : when user inserts a record into a table, a filegroup should be added to another database ??

Comment: by any way other than triggers??

Comment: @HossamElsagheer By a posting a message to a process queue. You will have to dig into this yourself because I have no experience with what you are trying to do. Possibly you could use something like MSMQ, or come up with your own queueing solution (eg post a message to a queue table, and have a process poll the queue for instance). Or alternatively, solve this from another layer than the database layer.

Comment: Service Broker is the queuing solution built into SQL Server.  Though even that may be overkill, this could probably be handled with a table (in another database) and a recurring batch job on a short (1 min or less) cycle.